# Белорусский и беларуский

Tags: словообразование, синонимы

Название Республики Беларусь в неофициальных текстах сейчас повсеместно употребляется в двух вариантах: Беларусь и Белоруссия. [У меня нет сомнений в нормативности обоих вариантов.]

Но как правильно образуются прилагательные от этих слов? Белоруссия - понятно: *белорусский*. А Беларусь? Правильно ли будет *беларуский*?

Слово *беларуский* сейчас точно используют, мне оно встречалось и в статьях, и вывесках. Честно говоря, для меня немного непривычно. Насколько нормативна такая форма?

Answer (score 9):

По-русски правильно только "белорусский".

На самом деле все не так.
Появление "слова" беларуский было предсказано вашим покорным слугой (не им одним, разумеется) ровно в тот момент, когда появилось "русское" слово Беларусь.
Оно изначально чуждо русскому правописанию, поскольку содержит "соединительную" гласную А.
Историческое **русское** написание: [Белорусь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C).

Чтобы как-то выкрутиться из очевидной коллизии филологи от политики объявили "Беларусь" прямым заимствованием, не подлежащим морфологическому членению.
Таким образом единым корнем тут объявлено все слово. 
Но даже это не даёт права на существование прилагательного "беларус(с)кий". Прилагательное-то никак нельзя объявить нечленимым заимствованием.

**yupaz**

> [@behemothus](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/445/behemothus), с Вами трудно общаться, когда Вы становитесь в позу "я тут один д'Артаньян".
>
> Кто-то здесь утверждал, что слово "беларуский" в русском языке нормативно?

Формально — нет. Фактически, вы поставили под сомнение обратное. 
Но, вообще говоря, я не ставил себе задачу точно отслеживать, кто и что сказал в деталях. Мое мнение в данном случае самодостаточно, я ни на кого не ссылаюсь.

> Я всего лишь прошу объяснить, почему Вы считаете что нет.

Я ответил, как мог.

> То, что "есть прилагательное "белорусский", оно покрывает все возможные значения" — ни разу не аргумент.

Вы же спрашивали, почему **я так думаю**, а не то, сколько раз это аргумент для Вас.
Для меня - аргумент повесомее всех разговоров о наполеонах и д'артаньянах. Новое слово в языке появляется, когда есть необходимость обозначить какое-то **новое** значение. Или в силу какого-то внутреннего языкового процесса, мощного влияния другого языка, например. В нашем случае и то, и другое исключается.

Какой аргумент Вас бы устроил? Тот, что никто (включая словари) не утверждал, что оно нормативно?

Comment: @behemothus, почему не может быть слова "беларусский"? Как тогда образуется прилагательное от слова Беларусь?

Comment: Никак. О том и речь.
А что вообще должно означать это прилагательное?
Есть прилагательное "белорусский", оно покрывает все возможные значения.  
  
Вас не смущает, что прилагательное от Уэльс - валлийский, от Манчестера - Манкунианский, от Ливерпуля - мерсисайдский, от Монако - монегасийский и прочая, и прочая, и прочая?

Comment: "прилагательное от Уэльс - валлийский, от Манчестера - Манкунианский, от Ливерпуля - мерсисайдский, от Монако - монегасийский"

Может, удивитесь, но большинство из этих слов я слышу впервые. И уверяю Вас, подавляющее большинство русскоговорящих тоже очень удивятся, если вы назовете The Beatles "мерсисайдская четвёркой". Прилагательные от всех перечисленных Вами слов, в которых за основу взята форма существительного, в русском языке существуют - см. словарь.

Причем примечательна форма прилагательного от слова Уэльс - уэльский (не уэльсский!). Почему тогда не может быть слова "беларуский"?

Comment: Все это очень интересно (особенно про большинство русскоговорящих, обожаю аргументацию типа "это всем известно"), но какое это отношение имеет к предмету? Да прилагательные существуют. Точно также *существует* прилагательное *белорусский*.
Вот "беларускаго" не существует - и случай этот вполне объясним даже с тех позиций, что я перечислил, хотя не только с тех. Главное то, что этим словом нечего обозначать.

>Уэльс - уэльский (не уэльсский!)  
  
Где Вы такое нашли - и к чему оно относится? Думаю, у большинство русскоговорящих (не волапюкоговорящих) глаза на лоб полезут.

Comment: Лезьте, глаза, на лоб : **Чарльз, принц Уэльский!!!**

Comment: Это титул. Грудо говоря - имя собственное. 
Ёще используется в отношении языка, думал Вы его вспомните. 
На самом деле, Вы только подтверждаете основную мысль. Если от Уэльса может быть уэльский (против общих правил с одним С, т.е. равнозначно Валлийскому), то почему же "белорусский" к "Беларусь" вызывает такое раздражение?

Comment: Лукашенко, Батько Беларуский (?!) Тоже титул.

Не знаю такого титула. Простите, хотелось бы уже по теме что-нибудь услышать. Вы настаиваете на нормативности "беларус(С)кий"? Если да, то в каком значении?  
>Неужели Расія, вот это номер...  

Именно так. а что Вас так удивлят?

Comment: @behemothus, с Вами трудно общаться, когда Вы становитесь в позу "я тут один д'Артаньян". Кто-то здесь утверждал, что слово "беларуский" в русском языке нормативно? Я всего лишь прошу объяснить, почему Вы считаете что нет. То, что "есть прилагательное "белорусский", оно покрывает все возможные значения" - ни разу не аргумент.

Comment: @yupaz, разделение синонимов было бы вполне возможно (русский-российский, манчестерский (к городу)-манкунианский (к футбольному клубу)), если б они ещё и не были абсолютными омофонами (с нарушением норм речи можно подчеркнуть белОрусский, но невозможно беларуский, а нуждается в нём как раз последнее). Думаю, если внешнеполитическая ситуация не изменится, вполне может появится слово "беларусинский" как принадлежащий государству в отличии от белорусский - к нации, но "беларусский" - изначально мертворождённое слово.

Answer (score 6):

Слово *"беларуский"* в русском языке - это явная неграмотность, привнесённая белорусскими шовинистами.

Во-первых; Почему нет удвоенных "С"? Если к корню Беларус прибавить суффикс -ск, то будет белару**сс**кий.

А во-вторых; слово *Беларусь* относится к 3 склонению, и при образовании прилагательного должен добавиться суффикс -ин (или -ен). Например, *Маруся-марусин-марусинский, лошадь-лошадиный и пр*. Соответственно при словообразовании от *Беларусь* должно получится *беларусиный* или *беларусинский*, но никак не *беларуский*.

Мне могут возразить, что есть слова 3 скл. где нет суффикса -ин, например *Тверь-тверской, дверь-дверной*.
**Но.** Процесса падения редуцированных гласных в современном русском нет (да и гласного звука там теперь нет), так что убирать мягкость последнего согласного у нас нет никаких оснований. Тем более, что наши предки это **уже** сделали для получения слов **русский** и **белорусский**.

Comment: воляпюк-это искусственный язык, предшественник эсперанто?

Comment: @школяр-я, да. Сейчас это слово используют в почти только в иронически (в значении «тарабарщина») и подразумевают невразумительную, бедную, неграмотную речь с грубыми искажениями норм и правил языка, а также с нелепым словообразованием, элементами жаргона и т. д. К чему я и отнёс слово *беларуский*

Comment: >Беларуский - это воляпюк, придуманный "патриотически" настроенными белорусскими аборигенами.

Это уже за всеми мыслимыми рамками...

Comment: Марк Из, я не берусь утверждать, но мне казалось, что по правилам русского языка верный вариант все же "иранцы", а не "персы". Речь идёт не об основном населении, как Вы сказали, а о том, как правильно согласно нормам русского языка называть жителей Ирана. Также и беларусы. С Вашим: "но на национальности переименование государства никак не влияют", не соглашусь. В русском языке равно транслитерации подлежит не только слово «Беларусь», но и производные понятия народа этой страны и ее языка – как политическое значение, неотделимое от названия страны

Comment: >В русском языке равно транслитерации подлежит не только слово «Беларусь», но и производные понятия народа этой страны и ее языка – как политическое значение, неотделимое от названия страны

С чего вы так решили?
Житель Ирана можно назвать иранцем по гражданству, но по национальности он может быть кем угодно, курдом, азербайджанцем или представителем  титульной нации, *персом*, который говорит на персидском языке (фарси).

Я, как житель России, являюсь россиянином, но название моей нации *русский*, хотя слово "Русь", от которого образовано данное слово, уже историзм, такой земли нет на карте.

Comment: Вот чем плохи "острые" политические вопросы - от них невозможно отделаться. Рано или поздно всегда найдется кто-то, кому языковые вопросы - лишь средство для достижения политических сражений. 
Я-то тут стараюсь ни на полшага не выходить от лингвистики в сторону политики, но это мало помогает. 
Могу только повторить. Появление этого лингвоуродца было предсказано мной еще в 90-х. Невозможно, смирившись с чуждой русскому языку "Беларусью", оборонять остатки белорусских укреплений. 
Радует, что пока еще с китайцами отношения сложные. 
А то бы уже спорили, как правильно "Чжунь-го" или "Жонг-хуа"

Comment: МаркИз, может, стоит подредактировать ответ? Белорусский язык — не "воляпюк".

Comment: @Aer я про белорусский язык ничего подобного не писал, лишь про слово "беларуский"

Answer (score 6):

Не нужно путать два языка. По-русски в соответствии со всеми правилами образуется прилагательное БЕЛОРУССКИЙ, а по-белорусски это же прилагательное  - БЕЛАРУСКІ. Хотелось бы обратиться к Марку Из: белорусский язык - не воляпюк. Он существует, хотите вы этого или нет.

Comment: А я не говорю, что белорусский языка не существует. Я утверждаю, что слово *беларуский* - это воляпюк. По-русски нужно писать *белорусский*, а по-белорусски, как вы верно отметили, *беларускi*, и смешивать эти слова лишь в угоду политической конъюнктуры не следует.

Comment: >белорусский язык - не воляпюк. Он существует, хотите вы этого или нет.  
  
+многа.  

>Я утверждаю, что слово беларуский - это воляпюк.  
  
Что такое "воляпюк" в Вашем понимании?

Comment: @behemothus, см. 2 комментарий к моему ответу.

Comment: Да видел я. Дал Вам шанс исправиться. Вы им не воспользовались.
Не понимаете вы значения слов, которые употребляете.

Comment: @behemothus, может быть. Только вот определение слова я взял из [словаря](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/446/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%8E%D0%BA) см. 2 абзац.

Comment: Я не вижу здесь "определения". Вижу использование, никаким определением не предусмотренное. Простите.
"Волапюк" по всем определениям это язык,  а не слово какого-то языка, на что Вы так явно намекаете. Согласны?
ЗЫ И все бы ничего, но у Вас еще и оскорбительно для белорусов прозвучало, а они уж тут точно никаким боком. Ибо этот мертворожденный уродец рожден вполне себе русскими политиками, сначала понапридумывавшими всяких ТаллиННов и Кыргызстанов, а потом не знающих, как от них культурно избавится...

Answer (score 1):

Образование  прилагательных от имен собственных – задача не из простых, и она не решается простым добавлением суффикса СК к основе существительного. В этом случае решаются две основные задачи: найти удобную форму прилагательного (фонетическую и графическую) и минимально исказить исходное название, особенно иностранное. Особого внимания требуют к себе основы на С и СК. При  образовании прилагательного возможно частичное или полное наложение суффикса СК на основу, а также усечение основы, чтобы избежать стечения согласных, например:  Уэльс – уэльский (наложение СК на основу), дамаск – дамасский (усечение основы).  Для названия «Беларусь» приходится решать не две, а сразу три задачи:  кроме поиска гармоничной формы и минимального искажения имени собственного, дополнительно следует проявить  уважение к национальным традициям. Всем изложенным условиям лучше отвечает форма «беларуский» с наложением суффикса СК на основу. Она лучше сохраняет исходное существительное, отличает его от прежней «Белоруссии», в то время как «беларусский» выглядит как ошибочное написание буквы А в типично русском, а не  иностранном названии.

Answer (score 1):

Беларуса "Ввермина" поддерживал до последних двух абзацев. До этого всё шло правильно. Более того, слово Беларусь (или Белорусь) - единственное исконно русское название иностранного государства. В этом слове тот же корень, что и в слове "русский" (язык). Белоруссия - это озападеннинная форма слова Белорусь. Именно поэтому сейчас на ТВ и по радио старательно произносят уродливые для русского уха новые названия, типа Башкортостан, Тыва, Кыргызстан (вообще невыговариваемые), Молдова и т.д. (кстати, тогда должны быть: "молдОвский", "кЫргЫзы" (?)), но только не Баларусь! (Или Белорусь - это непринципиально для русского языка.) Главное - чтобы только древнее слово Русь не звучало! Вернусь к "Ввермину": Если Беларусь в русском языке - сам Бог велел, можно согласиться с "белАрус", но "бела/о/руский" с одним "с" - это уже, извините, не вашей языковой юрисдикции дело, дорогой земляк. Уж позвольте русскому языку самому образовывать прилагательные, как это принято именно в русском языке. После корня идет суффикс "-ск-", отсюда и само прилагательное "рус-ск-ий" и все остальные должны образовываться по этому правилу. Даже несмотря на то, что какой-то скудоумный чиновник от языка записал в словарь неправильную форму "уэльский" с одним "с". Это на совести того "русиста". Такие, как он, и сейчас уничтожают русский язык, вводя в словари несклоняемость, что противоречит законам русского языка, вводя в словари американизмы, сразу после первого раза их употребления в рекламе или в СМИ. Ничего, настанут времена и русский народ очистит родной язык от западенского мусора поганой метлой, как это сделали Японцы, Греки, Турки и др. Евреи и словаки вообще восстановили свои умершие языки - иврит и словацкий.  Индийцы поддерживают живым санскрит. Если русские - это народ, а не помойка, то придет время возвращения культурного самосознания.

Comment: Отлично сказано!
Только насчёт Башкортостана с Кыргызстаном небольшое уточнение. В тюркских языках, насколько я помню, все гласные должны быть либо переднеязычными, либо заднеязычными. А поскольку их республики "стАны" ("а" относится к гласным переднего ряда), то и звука "и" в названии быть не может. "КИргИзстАн" по-кыргызски просто не произнести, понимаете? А быть какими-то "кирьгизями" им обидно. Бог с ними, пусть будут кыргызами.)))))

Comment: Уважаемая, Жихарка! Скажите, какое нам дело то того, как произносится Ы или И во всех языках мира? Мы речь ведем исключительно о системе русского языка. И в русском языке все произноситься и писаться должно по законам РУССКОГО языка,а не всех остальных. Французы произносят фамилию Путин: путИн, т.к. во французском языке ВСЕ слова произносятся с ударением на последний слог.И плевать они хотели не только на наш язык,но и на политкорректность,и ДАЖЕ на риски в международных отношениях.И ТАК ВО ВСЕХ ЯЗЫКАХ.Только мы, русские, выгибаемся перед не только английским,но уже и перед тюркскими языками.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, все просто: по-русски "Белоруссия", " белорус"; по-белорусски "Беларусь", "беларус".

Comment: Да не проходит это. Политики от филологии пробили написание "Беларусь" как форму, закрепленную русским языком. Теперь от этого уродца уже не отвертеться. От него и хотят образовать "беларусский" отдельные граждане. И они по-своему правы: зачем останавливаться на полпути, даже в деле ижевательтсва над  родным языком?

Comment: В таком случае российские политики должны бы симметрично потребовать от белорусов писать на белорусском языке не "Расія", а "Россия"; не "Масква", а "Москва".

Comment: Российские политики давно никому ничего не нужны. )))  
Но дело даже не в этом.   
Аналогия не совсем уместная.  "Расія"/"Россия", "Масква"/"Москва" = это тонкости чисто орфографические, они определяются языком, а не политиками.  А вот "Беларусь"/"Белоруссия" - это принципиально иной вариант названия, т.е. искусственное введение в другой язык слова, аналог который и так в нем существует. Это как как бы немцы потребовали называть их и Германию на русском Дойчами и Дойчляндом.

Answer (score 0):

Если признать допустимым в русском языке слово "Беларусь", то должно быть "беларусский", по анаологии с "Русь" - "русский".

Ещё можно признать правильным не "Беларусь", а "Белорусь". Это не противоречит белорусскому закону, т.к. там сказано "Установить, что эти названия транслитерируются на другие языки в соответствии с белорусским звучанием". А по звучанию оно совпадает. И, кстати, в белорусском языке Россия будет "Расiя", то есть по звучанию аналогично, а по написанию нет.

Comment: Не получается тут аналогия. Посмотрите другие ответы. В "белорусский" "ский" - суффикс. Поэтому два с. Дальше. Что будет значить это новое образование? орфографический вариант уже имеющегося? А зачем? И главное.  Мы здесь говорим о языке русском. А кто и что там устанавливает в отношении транслитерации со стороны - это никакой силы не имеет.

Answer (score -1):

Господа, вы неправы. 
Верховный Совет БССР 19 сентября 1991 года принял «Закон Белорусской Советской Социалистической Республики о названии Белорусской Советской Социалистической Республики». В этом Законе еще до распада СССР наша БССР была переименована в Республику Беларусь (мой перевод на русский):

«Белорусскую Советскую Социалистическую Республику далее называть «Республика Беларусь», а в укороченных и составных названиях – «Беларусь».

И обращаю внимание на продолжение текста этого Закона:

«Установить, что эти названия транслитеруются на другие языки в соответствии с беларуским звучанием».

Транслитерация (Transliteration) - перевод одной графической системы алфавита в другую, то есть передача букв одной письменности буквами другой. Что означает, например, для русского языка, что в нем нет больше никакой «Белоруссии», а обязана быть только и именно одна «Беларусь».

Сегодня во всех официальных международных мероприятиях (саммиты СНГ, спортивные соревнования, торговые соглашения и пр.) это строго соблюдается: есть только название «Беларусь». В паспортах и прочих документах РБ на русском языке – тоже только «Беларусь», никакой «Белоруссии».

Общероссийский классификатор стран мира OK (MK (ИСО 3166) 004—97) 025-2001 (ОКСМ) (принят и введен в действие постановлением Госстандарта РФ от 14 декабря 2001 г. № 529-ст) тоже категоричен: он предусматривает только формы «Республика Беларусь» и «Беларусь», а какая-то фантастическая «Белоруссия» им не предусмотрена – такой страны не существует.

Главным в Законе о названии страны является пункт о ТРАНСЛИТЕРАЦИИ ее названия на другие языки мира (включая русский). Дело в том, что некоторые страны такого пункта не имеют и потому могут по-разному называться в разных языках: например, в русском нет никакой Норге, а есть Норвегия, вместо Данмарк – Дания, Суоми – Финляндия, Дойчланд – Германия, вместо Летува – Литва. Ни Финляндия, ни Германия, ни Летува не заявляли о том, что их самоназвания Суоми, Дойчланд и Летува транслитеруются на другие языки – и не просили другие страны их отныне называть именно так. А вот Беларусь именно это заявила в своем Законе. И точно так в свое время Персия попросила называть её Ираном, Цейлон – Шри-Ланкой, Берег Слоновой Кости – Кот д' Ивуаром, Бирма – Мьянмой, Северная Родезия – Замбией, Бенгалия – Бангладеш, Верхняя Вольта – Буркина Фасо. Именно под новыми названиями эти страны известны сегодня во всем мире, в том числе в РФ.

Если бы противники термина «Беларусь» в русском языке показали нам, что Россия пренебрегает этими правилами и продолжает называть Иран Персией, а Шри-Ланку Цейлоном – то в таком случае их мнение имело бы какую-то аргументацию. А в данном случае такая избирательность непонятна: чем же мы хуже Ирана или Шри-Ланки, если в России СМИ и просто россияне не желают признавать наше новое название и упрямо именуют старым несуществующим «Белоруссия»?

Тем не менее термин «Беларусь» все-таки СТАЛ ЯЗЫКОВОЙ РЕАЛИЕЙ русского языка, так как активно используется в ООН (где один из языков – русский) и всем государственным аппаратом РФ: всеми министерствами.

Таким образом, слово «Беларусь» стало частью русской лексики. Причем – используется не столько в быту, сколько в официозе, а это означает тенденцию вытеснения со временем старого слова «Белоруссия» и в разговорном русском. Пишется слово именно через «а», как этого и требует наш Закон о транслитерации названия страны – нигде в официальных документах РФ не используется слово «Белорусь» - ЕГО ПРОСТО НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ в русском языке.

В спорах со мной на эту тему многие российские «тугодумы» соглашались, что слово «Беларусь» стало частью русского языка из-за его использования российским официозом, но все равно упорствовали: мол, это слово «неправильное», а правильно – делать русскую соединительную «о».

Но если слово только ТРАНСЛИТИРУЕТСЯ на русский язык – то о каких же «нормах русского языка» можно говорить? Вот прямая аналогия: французское Кот д' Ивуар. Почему же никто равно не возмущается и не говорит, что по-русски правильно писать по-старому «Берег Слоновой Кости»? Или беларуский язык – это не такой же иностранный язык, как французский? Или Беларусь – это не суверенное государство, как Кот д' Ивуар, а часть РФ?

Коль «Беларусь» - языковая реалия русского языка, то как по правилам русского языка должно образовываться название гражданина Беларуси?
Правильно: белАрус.

Здесь возражения о соединительной «о» вообще неуместны, так как изначальное слово «Беларусь» образовано не по правилам русского языка. А на этот счет в русском языке свои нормы: корнем слова является в таком случае все слово «Беларусь» (а не два тут корня).

Вместо того чтобы воспринимать слово «Беларусь» как ЗАИМСТВОВАННОЕ из другого языка, россияне по инерции его делят на два корня – что противоречит правилам русского языка о заимствованных словах.

Следуя этому правилу, и в русском языке равно транслитерации подлежит не только слово «Беларусь», но и производные понятия народа этой страны и ее языка – как политическое значение, НЕОТДЕЛИМОЕ от названия страны. Они РАВНО ТРАНСЛИТИРУЮТСЯ в рамках транслитерации названия страны «Беларусь». Таким образом, автоматически подлежат транслитерации слова «беларус» и «беларуский язык».

Это тоже строго в рамках правил русского языка. Равно как слово «Беларусь» является заимствованным транслитерацией в русском языке и не подлежит делению на два корня – точно так заимствованное слово «беларуский» является КОРНЕМ до буквы «к» (согласно правилам русского языка, заимствованные слова являются корнями до своих окончаний).

И, как заимствованное слово русского языка, не подлежит аналогично ни делению на два корня, ни правилу русского языка по удвоению «с» между «с» в корне и суффиксом. Так как этого правила нет в исходом для транслитерации беларуском языке – а транслитерация, напомню, сохраняет нормы грамматики исходного языка СВОЕЙ СТРАНЫ. А главное: само слово «беларуский» - заимствованное, и в нем русский язык не имеет права вычленять суффиксы.

Что касается окончаний (автор статьи в журнале «Родина» утрировал: «ну нет, тогда уж «беларускава»), то вот как раз в этом вопросе, согласно нормам русского языка, должны уже соблюдаться нормы русского языка. Заимствованные в русский язык слова сохраняют свои иностранные корни, но имеют падежные формы уже по русским правилам. Так что и тут «мимо»...

Comment: >Таким образом, автоматически подлежат транслитерации слова «беларус» и «беларуский язык».

А при чём тут название государства и национальность? Я бы понял если бы вы отстаивали сохранение "а" в названии гражданина Беларуси, но на национальности переименование государства никак не влияют. Основное население Ирана, если вы так любите ссылаться на его опыт,  по прежнему персы.

Comment: "то вот как раз в этом вопросе, согласно нормам русского языка, должны уже соблюдаться нормы русского языка."
Улыбнуло...

"А главное: само слово «беларуский» - заимствованное, и в нем русский язык не имеет права вычленять суффиксы."
Русский язык имеет право делать всё что ему заблагорассудится.))))
Вы можете настаивать на каком угодно названии вашей страны, мы согласимся с любым вариантом, но вот образование прилагательного - это уже исключительно наше дело.

Comment: "Вы можете настаивать на каком угодно названии вашей страны," - это тоже неверно. Настаивать-то можно, но вот почему-то немцы или англичане не настаивают на Дойчлянде и Ингланде. Так же китайцы, американцы и японцы. А вот Буркина Фасо, Кот д'Ивуар и Беларусь настояли. Наверное этот  признак национальной гордости тех стран, которым больше гордиться нечем.